# MP4 is not playable after downloaded from web using PHP

Tags: php

I have a playable .mp4 file and I used this code to download the file using PHP.

Web browser downloads file ok, but the mp4 file is not playable after downloading.

Does the code have any issue?

```
<?php
// place this code inside a php file and call it f.e. "download.php"
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/video/";
$fullPath = $path."test_video.mp4";

if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }
}
fclose ($fd);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");` is not needed to download file. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download)

Second

change your header with,

```
header('Content-type: video/mp4');
header('Content-type: video/mpeg');
```

this should work.

Comment: If I changed it to video/mp4 then it shows the video on the web browser instead of downloading it.

Comment: You can force your browser to download in the headers.  See the answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091766/mp4-download-causes-browser-to-play-file-instead-of-download

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the repotations to comment. Please check your code for other files such as text or image.I think you must be getting an error there too.