# How to force download files through pafy and youtube-dl in Django webapp

Tags: django, youtube-dl, pafy

I have made a youtube video downloader app with django and pafy.

The problem in the final link which I am getting is something like https://r5---sn-gwpa-jj0z-blah-blah.

These links are opening files in the browser how to make them downloadable on clients machine?

The Template I am using to get the download link is,

```
{% for resolution,extension,file_size,url in streams %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ resolution }}</td>
        <td>{{ file_size }}</td>
        <td>{{ extension }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ url }}" download="{{ title }}.{{ extension }}" type="application/octet-stream" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" ></span> Download
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Is it possible to get the direct links from youtube-dl, I did a lot of searching but didn't found a valid answer nothing worked for me?

**Update**

Views.py

```
import pafy
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.defaultfilters import filesizeformat
from django.views import generic


def url_corrector(url):

    correct_url = url

    if 'm.' in url:
        correct_url = correct_url.replace('m.', '')

    if 'youtu.be' in url:
        video_id = url.split('/')[-1]
        correct_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + video_id

    return correct_url


class Download(generic.View):
    # """The view which handles the url and returns the download links."""

    template_name = 'download.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        url = request.POST['url']
        url = url_corrector(url)  # Converting the urls in a format that is supported by pafy.

        # if len(url.split("=")[-1]) != 11:  # Checks whether the url contains the 11 character unique video id.
        #     return HttpResponse('Enter correct url.')

        video = pafy.new(url)  # creates a pafy object for a given youtube url.

        stream = video.streams  # both video and audio
        video_audio_streams = list()  # list of all the videos which also contain audio
        for s in stream:
            video_audio_streams.append(
                [s.resolution, s.extension, filesizeformat(s.get_filesize()), s.url + "&title=" + video.title])

        stream_video = video.videostreams  # only video
        video_streams = list()  # list of all the dash video formats(only video)
        for s in stream_video:
            video_streams.append(
                [s.resolution, s.extension, filesizeformat(s.get_filesize()), s.url + "&title=" + video.title])

        stream_audio = video.audiostreams  # only audio
        audio_streams = list()  # list of all the dash audio formats(only audio)
        for s in stream_audio:
            audio_streams.append(
                [s.resolution, s.extension, filesizeformat(s.get_filesize()), s.url + "&title=" + video.title])

        return render(request, self.template_name,
                      {'url': request.POST['url'], 'title': video.title, 'streams': video_audio_streams,
                       'desc': video.description, 'likes': video.likes,
                       'dislikes': video.dislikes, 'thumb': video.bigthumbhd,
                       'duration': video.duration, 'views': video.viewcount,
                       'stream_video': video_streams, 'stream_audio': audio_streams})
```

Comment: you need to set headers, see here for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091766/mp4-download-causes-browser-to-play-file-instead-of-download

Comment: Thanks sir, Bu how to set headers in django project?

Comment: Done sir, Kindly have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pafy is just giving the direct links to the video files. Video is on google servers, so even if you have `download` attribute in your html the it won't work because the video is not on same domain therefore you can't control the headers. What you can do is [download](http://pythonhosted.org/Pafy/#stream-download-example) the video file temporarily on your server and serve it to the user.

**EDIT:**
One possible workaround is `alt + click` on download links. It will download the file instead of playing it. I tried triggering `alt+click` on normal clicks too using js but it won't work. So you will have to `alt+click` manually every time.

Comment: Yes it didn't work, after submitting the form I have a template where I loop over all the available extensions and quality available for video. Here is the a tag

Comment: `<td><a href="{{ url }}" download="{{ title }}.{{ extension }}" type="application/octet-stream" ><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" ></span> Download</a></td>
            </tr>`

Comment: I am using chrome after the template is rendered I see many options of downloading files with download links and when I click on them they start playing on browser, I have taken help of this repo https://github.com/apoorvaeternity/Youtube-Video-Downloader

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, means a lot

Comment: Oh thanks for the help, I will drop this project for now. Thanks again!

Comment: pafy has a method .download(), https://pythonhosted.org/Pafy/#stream-download-example look here for more details. Sorry couldn't help much it will be a lot of code for downloading the file, encoding it in blob or something like that and sending it user then deleting the file from server..

Comment: Actually, this app was a part of a project I thought integrating it would be cool, I don't want to make things much complicated so leaving this, and thanks you gave your time for me learned some new things just because of you, So you are the hero of the day for me.

Comment: So user have to press alt+click everytime? what about the mobile users?

Comment: alt+click might not even work in all desktop browsers, that's why its a workaround not a solution. Since the file is not on your server you don't have much control over it. Full proof solution is to download the file on your server and then user can download it from there. but then your server will start getting filled up, so will have to run some cron job to delete old videos automatically from server. Its a lot of work.

Comment: Yes that's why I dropped the plan!