# How to Download video tag using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link that I want to download the video from.

```html
<video name="media">
 <source src="https://foo.bar" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I want to be able to download the vid to the user storage using javascript.

Comment: Are you saying you want to download the video from someone else's website in order to play it, or that you want to download it to the user's computer?

Comment: to the user's computer

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311645/download-image-with-javascript

Comment: Why local storage? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403706/save-a-video-in-local-storage

Comment: Or are you wanting to store the video in `localStorage`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: not local storage, user storage*

Comment: I hope your videos are small. Most browsers will not allow more than 10 mb in localstorage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mp4 Download causes browser to play file instead of download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091766/mp4-download-causes-browser-to-play-file-instead-of-download)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have the link, you can trigger it manually.

```
var a = $("<a>")
    .attr("href", "LINK HERE")
    .attr("download", "vid.mp4")
    .appendTo("body");

a[0].click();

a.remove();
```

Comment: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$' on 'CommandLineAPI': '<a>' is not a valid selector.`

Answer (score 6):

Just add an anchor tag with the same link and a `download` attribute:

```
<a href="https://foo.bar" download>
    Download Me!
</a>
```

Comment: I want to download it the user storage*

Comment: As in, their `Downloads` folder?

Comment: @Pingo, I've changed my answer now I know that you are going for user's download folder.